# logrotate not splitting log file

Tags: logs, logrotate

I am trying to get logrotate to work on my OpenResty server logs. My logrotate configuration file `/etc/logrotate.d/openresty` should execute daily which is default behavior and I'm trying to run it manually with `sudo logrotate -vfd /etc/logrotate.d/openresty`.

This is how I configured it:

```
/home/appname/logs/openresty/*.log /var/log/openresty/*.log {
        su root root
        size 100M
        missingok
        rotate 14
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 0660 root root
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi \
        endscript
}
```

But this is how my log directory (`~/logs/openresty`) looks like:

```
total 1.3G
-rw-r----- 1 root     root 1.2G Jul 23 09:41 access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm  154K Jul 13 11:43 access.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm  159M Jul 13 11:18 access.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root     root 572K Oct  5 04:24 error.log
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  62K Jul 23 02:52 error.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm   12K Jul 13 10:55 error.log.2.gz
```

As you can see the main log file is way above the 100 MB limit and it's not splitting as it should. Also not sure why it's named `access.log.1` instead of `access.log` (which is how it's configured in the server).

When I run `sudo logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/openresty` I get the following output:

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/openresty

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /home/appname/logs/openresty/*.log /var/log/openresty/*.log  104857600 bytes (14 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /home/appname/logs/openresty/error.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/openresty/access.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/openresty/error.log
  log does not need rotating
rotating log /var/log/openresty/access.log, log->rotateCount is 14
dateext suffix '-20201005'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.14.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.15.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 14),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.14.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.13.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.14.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 13),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.13.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.12.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.13.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 12),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.12.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.11.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.12.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 11),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.11.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.10.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.11.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 10),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.10.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.9.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.10.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 9),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.9.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.8.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.9.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 8),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.8.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.7.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.8.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 7),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.7.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.6.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.7.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 6),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.6.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.5.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.6.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 5),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.5.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.4.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.5.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 4),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.4.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.3.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.4.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 3),
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.2.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.3.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.1.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.2.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log.0.gz to /var/log/openresty/access.log.1.gz (rotatecount 14, logstart 1, i 0),
old log /var/log/openresty/access.log.0.gz does not exist
log /var/log/openresty/access.log.15.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
running prerotate script
renaming /var/log/openresty/access.log to /var/log/openresty/access.log.1
creating new /var/log/openresty/access.log mode = 0660 uid = 0 gid = 0
```

However absolutely nothing gets rotated on `~/logs/openresty`. It just ignores the whole thing.

And on `/var/log/openresty` a new empty log `access.log` gets created but the old one doesn't get split and is still over 100 MB:

```
total 379M
-rw-rw---- 1 root     root    0 Oct  5 08:51 access.log
-rw-r----- 1 root     root 366M Oct  5 08:53 access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root     root 5.1M Jul 23 09:41 access.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm  8.0K Jul 13 11:42 access.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root     root 8.2M Jul 13 11:18 access.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm   70K Oct  4 14:17 error.log
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  948 Jun 26 10:24 error.log.1
```

Also for some reason the server keeps writing on `access.log.1` instead of `access.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Logrotate is working but openresty does not know that it should write to a new log file (so it keeps writing to `access.log.1`).

You need to add a `postrotate` script to your config:

```
postrotate
  /usr/local/bin/openresty -s reload
endscript
```

(I'm not familiar with openresty, so the `openresty -s reload` is just a guess - you need to look it up in your documentation)

Comment: Alright adding the postrotate script with `service openresty reload` did create the new file. But `access.log.1` is still 1.2GB. Why isn't logrotate splitting and compressing it?

Comment: It's not splitting because it's already done with that file (it grew after it was processed). Compression is delayed with the `delaycompress` option. use `nodelaycompress`.

Comment: I changed it to `nodelaycompress` and saw no changes. How can I split and compress `access.log.1` as if it was done by logrotate then?

Comment: the changes will likly take effect once it has something to do (when the logfile grows beyond the configured size) - access.log.1 will not be split but compressed. However with postrotate it will work correctly in the future.

Comment: I'm noticing logrotate isn't running daily... I have that configuration file at `/etc/logrotate.d/openresty`. Then I have `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` which runs `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf` and `logrotate.conf` has `include /etc/logrotate.d` which should run all logrotate configurations under that directory daily, right? What am I missing here? Why isn't it running daily?